# Hiding .php in subfolders with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to hide .php in my URLS. it works with folowwing .htaccess in root files but not in subfolders. 
Like it works for https://example.com/demo
but when i try to login or signup it dont work and gives 404. 
my login URL is below

https://example.com/demo/login.php ( then login.php page from root calls the login.php page in the inc folder)

Please guide

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless PHP URLs
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess and https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Comment: i have seen that but couldn't get the idea. If please fix the htaccess to work as i need, i will highly appreciate.

Comment: We don't have similar environment you have to do it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You should use RewriteBase then verify if it's a not a dir and simply remove the .php. Try this and let me know.

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

> Attention GoDaddy users: In order to remove the extensions you need to enable MultiViews before. The code should look like this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
```

If you’re worried that search engines might index these pages as duplicate content, add a  meta tag in the head of your HTML file

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://alexcican.com/post/single-post" />
```

Comment: nice suggest! about godaddy (which is a horrible service) I use `Options +MultiViews`

Comment: the above didn't work for me. it is showing .php in my URL's. My server is Apache and hosted on digital ocean. 
I appreciate the help from you, but it is not working. 

i am seeing this https://example.com/demo/about.php

Comment: You might need to add an htaccess in your sub directory or be more specific in your root htaccess for that particular directory,

Comment: Patrick, that means i have to place the .htaccess in subfolders also?
i have placed in the root (public_html > script name > .htaccess
and me login pages are here

public_html > script name > inc > login, register pages,
public_html > script name > include > headers, footers, navigations, config files

Comment: Yes anywhere you have a php page that loads in the url (probably not include folder as that is usually included in an other php file) so only top level php files or you can be more specific in the root htaccess file so the "demo" folder has a set of rules.